# Why do hyperbolic projection models use a two-sheeted hyperboloid?

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, noneuclidean-geometry

I was under the impression that the reason hyperbolic geometry counters spherical geometry is that a hyperboloid has negative Gaussian curvature everywhere. However, it seems that this only applies to a one-sheeted hyperboloid, whereas a two-sheeted hyperboloid has elliptical geometry and has positive curvature everywhere. Why then, do models like the Poincare model and the Klein model utilize the two-sheeted hyperboloid?

Comment: The Poincaré and Klein (not to mention the half-plane) models exist in the Euclidean plane, which has Gaussian curvature zero. The *metrics* applied to these models are what allows them to exhibit properties of a negative-curvature surface. Likewise with the 2-sheeted hyperboloid: as a generic surface, it has positive Gaussian curvature, but equipped with an appropriate metric, the geometry on it emulates constant negative curvature. The "natural" surface of negative curvature whose "natural" metric matches hyperbolic geometry is the [pseudosphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudosphere).

Comment: I presume you are asking about the [hyperboloid model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperboloid_model) of hyperbolic geometry, in which case you should read carefully what the metric is: unlike the metric on a sphere, it is **not** the restriction of the ordinary Riemannian metric on Euclidean space; it is instead the restriction of a Lorentzian metric.